# nvidia-smi: command not found Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I need to use GPU in my Jetson Xavier NX Developer Kit ubuntu18.04 arm_64
When I run `nvcc --version` the output is:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_28_22:34:44_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.300
Build cuda_10.2_r440.TC440_70.29663091_0
```

...but when I run run `nvidia-smi` the output is:

```
bash: nvidia-smi: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 ships the `nvidia-smi` binary in the `nvidia-utils-390` package. Unfortunately this isn't built for the arm64 architecture, as you can see here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nvidia-utils-390

Newer versions of Ubuntu such as 22.04 ship it in a newer package `nvidia-utils-510` for arm64. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/nvidia-utils-510

So I suspect you need a newer image for your jetson device. There's a [thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/update-ubuntu-on-jetson-xavier-nx/220643) about is on the nvidia developer forum.